# Selenium IE Webdriver showing "Only Local connection are allowed" in TestNG

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I am trying to launch my application in IE browser in selenium using TestNG framework. But, after the IE browser is launched, the Eclipse console shows an error that "Only Local Connection are allowed".

My IE browser is set to zoom 100%, the Protected mode is set as expected. I am executing the script on Windows 10 64 Bit. Selenium version is 3.0.1 and IEDriverServer.exe is 64-bit as well.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/close/23077

Comment: Zoom 100% Protected mode - Either enabled for all zones or disabled for all zones. worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- When you are executing your automation script you might connected to VPN or any private network.
- Please connect to open network and then give a try to execute your script. It might resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Narendra, I am trying to execute my script on Server Machine and Eclipse,java,TestNG,Selenium all are  located and installed on Server machine only. is it still possible that     It is not allowing selenium driver to access the server IP.                      Actually i cant access my client URL on local machine so we install all required s/w there only..  And I usually access URL of my application through rdc(Remote Connection) to client server

Comment: Agree. But giving first try you should use client machine as other than server. Once all config and everything start working, you access client on server machine itself. This would be good solution. Because in your previous case - one error/dependancy may affect other part

Answer (score 0):

Although, the error that you are stating is just an informational message and it should not stop your execution. But, if you are facing problem while execution you would need to check few combinations of IEDriverServer and selenium version to resolve the issue

I would suggest you to use the 32 bit version of IEDriverServer even if your machine has 64 bit OS because I faced slowness issue while using 64 bit IEDriver

Settings -

**Zoom** 100%
**Protected mode** - Either enabled for all zones or disabled for all zones.
**IEDriver.exe** - Try using 32 bit
**Selenium biniding** - 1st try with 3.0. If it doesn't work, try 2.53.1